# Compressing using JPEG but no quality degradation (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, jpeg, image-compression

Good day,

I am trying to show that compressing an image many-many times 
(extremely many, as in 500 times), will show quality degradation. And from
what I understand, this can happen when an image is saved many-many times
in JPEG. I tried writing a MATLAB code to do this:

```
    clc;close all;clear;

for i = 1:500
    if i==1
        a = imread('e:\ismoka_small.jpg');
        currFileName = 'e:\multipleJpegs\001.jpg';
    else
        a = imread(currFileName);
        if i <= 10
            zeross = '00';
        elseif i <= 100
            zeross = '0';
        elseif i <= 1000
            zeross = '';
        end
        currFileName = ['e:\multipleJpegs\' zeross num2str(i-1) '.jpg'];
    end

    imwrite(a, currFileName, 'jpeg');
end
```

The end result however shows that no degradation occurs, and all the 500 images have the same file size. I was wondering if anyone can help me and explain why this is the case?
Or do I have it wrong regarding the JPEG algorithm? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You understood wrongly. Saving an image 1000 times does not necessarily needs to degrade it.

Comment: actually i saw a demo of this on one website. Forget the link. It showed how the image was of extremely bad quality after 500 saves. Maybe I've to open it first and then save.

Comment: Here is the link btw.... http://petapixel.com/2010/02/04/saving-jpeg-photos-hundreds-of-times/

Comment: Thanks for it. What I meant is exactly what Mark Ransom explained. Eventually, after not too long, the "compresion" will not compress anymore because the information is already compresed. As an analogy, if you compress  .zip file 1000 times it wont eventully become very small, there is a moment where the new zip file does not reduce the size any more, and that is most likely to happen in the first 5 compresions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @AnderBiguri. Yes, that makes perfect sense. Perhaps the authors of the webpage were actually compressing (re-saving) at different JPEG qualities. That's the only plausible explanation that I can think of for their continued degradation after so many iterations...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loss caused by JPEG compression is due to quantization, which is essentially rounding or truncation. If you're always saving with the same quality setting, it's quite possible that the quantization process produces the same results each time, especially if you do this many times - the pixels will degrade until they reach a point where they survive the round trip, then they won't change any more.

If you make any changes to the image before resaving, those changes will cause degradation in the 8x8 or 16x16 region where the changes were made.

If you save at different quality settings every time, you'll get different quantization each time and the image will definitely degrade, even sometimes if you use a higher setting.

Here I've repeated the test with my own image, using Python's PIL to open and save the image 100 times. I also opened and saved it one more time, to see if there was any additional degradation - there was no difference. I've resaved the JPEGs as PNG to prevent any further losses from StackOverflow's image engine.

Although there are measureable differences between the first and 100th saves, they are insignificant in comparison to the difference between the original and the first.

Original:
[image: Original]

First save:
[image: First save]

100th save:
[image: 100th save]

Comment: Thank you Mark Ransom. I understand that that's the case as well. I actually saw this one post at http://petapixel.com/2010/02/04/saving-jpeg-photos-hundreds-of-times/ , and it talked about this. However, the author did everything in photoshop (and he mentioned a 10/12 quality setting... not sure whether he was alternating between the two). If he alternated, then I believe it would be possible to see degradation :) Agian, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: This is a very good explanation @MarkRansom :) Thank you for your efforts.

I am not wondering how the authors in the website I mentioned actually did it. I could only get what they get, if I use a lesser quantization matrix... Maybe that's what they did, but without realizing? 

I also tried saving many times using the pixlr image editor... Each time using a different setting (lower percentage, which I assume means using a different quantizaiton matrix). Still, results were the same, and file size was also the same.

Answer (score 2):

You're simply reading and saving the file as is. You're not reprocessing it in any way. I don't know how you do that in matlab, but you must open it, convert to image, and then save that image as JPEG. That's whre the degradation will occur. And yes, you'll see the degradation because JPEG is a lossy compression algorithm. However, the quality loss can't be measured by the file size.

You'll see the greates degradation on sharp edges: for example the borders of a black figure on a white background. The degradation is greater when you choose the higher compression rates or lower quality settings.

*NOTE: thanks to denver's comment, let's make it clear that there are also lossless JPEG formats: JPEG-LS and JPEG2000, but they're really unusual. If you use one of this lossless formats no matter how many times you compress and decompress and image, it will keep exactly like it was originally*

Comment: There are lossless JPEG compression schemes.

Comment: Thanks JotaBe... your and Denver's comment made me rethink on how to reformulate the problem. Now I think I have what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure.  The quality should default to 75, causing a little degradation.  You could try the following tests.

1) Save the original image with different qualities to see if you can tell the difference.

```
imwrite(a, "75.jpg", 'jpeg', 'Mode', 'lossy', 'Quality', 75);
imwrite(a, "50.jpg", 'jpeg', 'Mode', 'lossy', 'Quality', 50);
```

2) Set the quality setting lower in your loop to see if it makes the effect more pronounced.

3) You can confirm the quality is decreasing each iteration by loading the image from the previous iteration and subtracting.  If the result is zero you are not changing the image.

Comment: Thanks Denver :) Yeps, this will most definitely (or most probably?) show some degradation. I was refering to this post (http://petapixel.com/2010/02/04/saving-jpeg-photos-hundreds-of-times/) ... and tried to do it in MATLAB.

Comment: BTW Denver... you comment is very useful. Made me think. Say I open the image for the first time. And save it as JPEG at 75% quality. Next time I open it... I save it at 75% quality again, but this time, it would be 75% from the previously degraded image (of 75% of the original). So it makes sense to keep decreasing the final parameter in the matlab imwrite function call :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction  :)

Comment: @Alfian the quality setting is not a percentage, it's just a number that is used to trim a quantization table. The effects don't add or multiply, it's much more subtle than that.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRansom ... Yes  I understand that now. Thanks for clarifying :)